# Hover effect is affecting them all at once, not individually

Tags: html, css, hover

I have been looking through for the cause of my problem and I haven't had any luck finding anything. I'm not entirely sure if this is my own stupidity or just purely lack of knowledge.

I don't know a lot about coding and I've had a super long day so I may have over looked something. Here is a basic idea of what I'm trying to do.

I want a list of 5 options, and they all have a block under the window so when rolled over it shows this block. (indicated by colour)

Now what I've created when rolled over they all show up, why is this?

Here is the example of what I've created

**HTML**

```
<div id="nature">
<a class="sound">
    <h4>Forest</h4>

    <div class="preview" style="background:red;">
    </div>
</a>

<a class="sound">
    <h4>Storm</h4>

    <div class="preview"style="background:blue;" >
    </div>
</a>

<a class="sound">
    <h4>Winter</h4>

    <div class="preview"style="background:lightblue;" >
    </div>
</a>

<a class="sound">
    <h4>Dusk</h4>

    <div class="preview"style="background:pink;" >
    </div>
</a>

<a class="sound">
    <h4>ocean</h4>

    <div class="preview"style="background:yellow;" >
    </div>
</a>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nature {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.sound {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 20%;
    height: 130px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    background: green;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s;
    -webkit-transition: .5s;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
}
.sound:hover {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.sound .preview {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
    margin: 50px 0 0 0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7t4JS/)

Comment: I think you're doing this the wrong way. When the user scrolls to the bottom, everything is visible. Would'nt it be better to hide them completely when not visible?

Comment: I think you're right thinking about it now yes, so if toggle the visibility of the preview through jquery it wouldn't have that issue. But would it hopefully still target them separately?

Comment: i think it has to do with the effect impacting the containing div. not 100% on the solution out of the box, i am tinkering with it atm. though in the mean time you may want to look at @DanielLisik comment. makes a good point. if you take them out of the container the effect does only effect the one you hover over.

Comment: this is not in the position you want but does show that the effect only applies to one of the items http://jsfiddle.net/7t4JS/4/

Comment: I appreciate that solution for sure, just trying to think of the more efficient solution suggested by @DanielLisik

Comment: Do u mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/7t4JS/15/ ?

Comment: I have fixed this issue going off what @DanielLisik mentioned, thank you for everyones comments. Really appreciate all your time!

Comment: Is it to late with a CSS solution? http://jsfiddle.net/DanielLisik/G4qk6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

easiest way;

```
#nature > a {
  position: relative;
}
.sound {
bottom:-50px;
}
.sound:hover {
bottom:0;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u3ssV/

p.s. also, You can wrap Your content in container with overflow set to hidden..
or i still dont get the point (?) :)

Answer (score -2):

You are applying the :hover effect to .sound, which is the *class* that is applied to all of the  blocks. Therefore when it triggers on any one of those items, the entire class is affected, and all blocks using that class change.

Try id's (identified by #idName in the css) to handle them individually. There may also be a better way to do this with classes to isolate the change that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I have actually tried using #id's instead also thinking the same as you but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Yep. Just checked. I shouldn't have answered off the cuff. I'll edit my answer if I think of something.

Comment: it has to do with the impact of the animation on the containing div.